# Django forms - not all data sent to the server

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x, django-forms

I have a form on my website that takes file upload and one text field. File is encrypted data, text file is the key to decrypt it. Code:

forms.py

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField(required=False)
    accessCode = forms.CharField(label=False, required=False)

    def process(self):
        file = "empty"
        if self.is_valid():
            file = self.cleaned_data.get('file')
            access_code = self.cleaned_data.get('accessCode')
            print("1. access code = %s" % access_code)
            file = file.read()
            context = {
                'file_data': file,
                'access_code': access_code,
            }
        return context
```

web:

```
<form action="/encryption/decrypt/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ upload_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

It looks like everything is sent OK, but when I just try to print values, as file content and input filed content it doesn't work

views.py:

```
def decrypt(request):
    upload_form = UploadForm(files=request.FILES)
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        post_data = upload_form.process()
        access_code = post_data.get('access_code', 'No Access Code')  
        salt = post_data.get('file_data', 'no file data')
        print("ACCESS CODE %s" % access_code)
        print("SALT = %s" % salt)
```

salt is printed correctly by access_code is empty, I have no idea why... I'm guessing that you can't just include upload and text file in one form, but I'm not sure how to fix it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't pass the `request.POST` as a parameter to the form. Just passing the `request.FILES` won't make the form understand where's the `accessCode` coming from. So according to [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads), you should:

```
upload_form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot request.POST fixed the problem! this worked the first part was missing! it's not a bug I'm actually passing this from forpms.py to views.py in "context" dictionary as access_code.

Comment: Yea I realized that, I edited my answer. Sorry about that.